# Local Build Server On Desktop

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a local build server that I can install on my machine (Windows 7) and it will then every x minutes compile my solution, run all unit tests and notify me if the build fails or a unit test fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest CruiseControl.Net as can be found [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET).

Answer (score 1):

Most build servers like CruiseControl.Net or TeamCity are built to run on a separate machine. That doesn't mean you can't run them locally

You might also want to look at nAnt or MSBuild to script your build and unit-tests (you'll have to do this with cc.net and teamcity anyway) and then periodically run it from a powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

Hudson build server: [hudson-ci.org](http://hudson-ci.org/)

It has a great UI that allows most configuration to be done easily.  It has a ton of plugins that can be installed and configured, also through the UI.

Finally, it has the Chuck Norris plugin.  How can you NOT use it? ;-)